# Como buscar substrings em um texto e armazena-las em uma váriavel C#

Tags: c#, array, string, algoritmo-de-busca, armazenamento

Preciso que leia um texto e encontre as palavras que comecem com LU- e pegue os números que venham em seguida, armazene tudo e me mostre depois, e precisa pegar mais de um código

```
 string texto = "uhgskuh LU-65498709634 HJVSHAS LU-12343438945";
 string LU = "LU-";
 var csd = texto.Substring(texto.IndexOf(LU,texto.IndexOf(LU)+1),14);
 Console.WriteLine(csd);
 Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Ajudaria explodir a string pelos espaços e do array resultante filtrar as strings que iniciam com `"LU-"`? Veja exemplo: https://ideone.com/qrL1ys

Answer (score 1):

usando `System.Linq` fica assim

```
string texto = "uhgskuh LU-65498709634 HJVSHAS LU-12343438945";
string LU = "LU-";

var list = texto.Split(' ')
                .Where(t => t.Contains(LU))
                .Select(t => t.Replace(LU, ""))
                .ToList();
```

- `texto.Split(' ')`: Isso divide a string texto em um array de strings usando os espaços em branco como delimitadores. O resultado é um array contendo partes da string original.
- `Where(t => t.Contains(LU))`: Isso filtra apenas os elementos do array que contêm a substring "LU-". Isso significa que você está interessado apenas nas partes da string original que possuem "LU-".
- `Select(t => t.Replace(LU, ""))`: Isso remove a substring "LU-" de cada elemento no array. O resultado é uma lista contendo apenas os números após "LU-".
- `ToList()`: Converte a sequência resultante em uma lista.

No final, a lista list conterá apenas os números que estão após "LU-" na string original. Isso é uma maneira de extrair esses números usando LINQ.

Para usar o LINQ vc pode consultar a pag [Trabalhar com a LINQ (Consulta Integrada à Linguagem)](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/working-with-linq)

Answer (score -3):

```
string texto = "uhgskuh LU-65498709634 HJVSHAS LU-12343438945";
string LU = "LU-";

// Cria uma lista para armazenar os códigos
List<string> codigos = new List<string>();

// Itera sobre todas as ocorrências da substring "LU-"
for (int i = texto.IndexOf(LU); i >= 0; i = texto.IndexOf(LU, i + 1)) {

    // Obtém a substring com o código
    string codigo = texto.Substring(i + 2, 14);

    // Adiciona o código à lista
    codigos.Add(codigo);
}

// Imprime os códigos
foreach (string codigo in codigos) {
    Console.WriteLine(codigo);
}
```

2º

```
string texto = "uhgskuh LU-65498709634 HJVSHAS LU-12343438945";
string[] strings = texto.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Cria uma lista para armazenar os códigos
List<string> codigos = new List<string>();

// Itera sobre todas as strings na matriz
foreach (string string in strings) {

    // Verifica se a string começa com "LU-"
    if (string.StartsWith("LU-")) {

        // Obtém a substring com o código
        string codigo = string.Substring(2, 14);

        // Adiciona o código à lista
        codigos.Add(codigo);
    }
}

// Imprime os códigos
foreach (string codigo in codigos) {
    Console.WriteLine(codigo);
}
```

Este código irá imprimir o mesmo resultado do código anterior.